# Selecting Dictionary item based on custom classes instead of keys

Tags: unity, c#, software-engineering

I am attempting to write my own path finding code for a game I'm working on that will implement a form of the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).  I store my nodes of the path finding system as a class called nodes and add these to a dictionary with their position in world space as the key for the dictionary.  Here's the problem.  At one point I need to test the dictionary and return from it the node with the lowest "f" value.  I came across the [morelinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable/) MinBy function with seemed promising, but so far have not had any luck getting it to work. Here is a stripped down version of the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MoreLinq;

public class GMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Dictionary<Vector3, Node> vectorNodesOpen = new Dictionary<Vector3,Node>();
    public Dictionary<Vector3, Node> vectorNodesClosed = new Dictionary<Vector3,Node>();

    private KeyValuePair<Vector3, Node> currentNode = new KeyValuePair<Vector3,Node>();

    private bool goal;
    private bool findingPath;

    void Start()
    {
        goal = false;
        findingPath = false;
    }

    public void addNodes()
    {
        //several nodes get added to the dictionary based on the A* algorithm
        //ending way point and beginning waypoint are stored as Vector3
    }


    public class Node
    {
        public int h { get; set; }
        public int g { get; set; }
        public int f { get; set; }
        public Vector3 pos { get; set; }
        public Vector3 parentNodeVector { get; set; }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(findingPath)
         while (!goal)
            {
                currentNode = new KeyValuePair<Vector3, Node>(vectorNodesOpen.MinBy(x => x.Value.f).Key, vectorNodesOpen[vectorNodesOpen.MinBy(x => x.Value.f).Key]);  //This is the line in which I'm attempting to get the node in the open list with the smallest f value.
                vectorNodesClosed.Add(vectorNodesOpen.MinBy(x => x.Value.f).Key, vectorNodesOpen[vectorNodesOpen.MinBy(x => x.Value.f).Key]);
                vectorNodesOpen.Remove(vectorNodesOpen.MinBy(x => x.Value.f).Key);  // remove current from open.

                if (currentNode.Value.pos == waypointEnd)   // if current node = end position we are done.
                {
                    goal = true;
                }

                addNodes(currentNode.Value.pos, waypointEnd);  //Add and update nodes
    }




}
```

The line that is giving me trouble is the first line inside the while loop.

I need a way to return the Dictionary item with the smallest "F" value, this would be pretty easy if it were an integer but the F value resides in the Node class.  I don't have to use MoreLinq,  I would be happy to do it any other way that someone can come up with.  Cheers!

*One more note:  the code above is incomplete in an effort to minimize it down to only what is necessary to understand the problem more complete code can be provided if necessary.

Comment: There is a solution for this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/102398/731620

Comment: @ratchet freak Just got the priority queue added to my project but noticed it target the 4.5 framework.  I'm in 3.5.  Think this will be a problem?

Comment: If it compiles it's probably fine

Comment: That's what I figured.  Thanks mate!  So far this seems to be exactly what I need.